# adding row to rich:datatable for a few seconds (notification)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working with richFaces - rich:dataTable. 
I need to delete some rows and then show a notification for few seconds as new row (after thead) and then it (row with notification) will disappear.

In JSF I can't give unique ID or name to my table, so I don't know how to find it in the DOM. Maybe then I can add some jQuery row code.

Comment: Is strange that you can't add a unique ID to a JSF component, basically you could do it by just adding `id="dtMyData"`. Also, is not very good to add a row just to show your messages, instead use `rich:messages` or `h:messages` for an elegant way to show messages to the application users.

Comment: Did you try to add id? In source file you will see something like id="myform:dtMyData:j_dk0:0", cause JSF changing it. I can use the H:messages, but I need it like jQuery notification, flashing 3 seconds and disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have stated, you can do something like this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:dataTable id="dtMyData" value="#{bean.lstData}" var="data">
        <!-- column definitions -->
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The HTML rendered would be like

```
<form id="myForm">
    <table id="myForm:dtMyData">
        <!-- rows auto generated -->
    </table>
</form>
```

And you can find it in your DOM by using the simplest JS

```
document.getElementById('myForm:dtMyData')
```

Also, you can use `<rich:dataTable>` tag component instead of `<h:dataTable>` and there would be no problems.

You can "remove" the rows by your own using JavaScript/jQuery or just by removing the items in the list and rerendering the datatable using an `<a4j:commandButton render="dtMyData">` (instead of commandbutton you can use `<a4j:commandLink>`).

To show messages to the user after firing an ajax action, you can use this richfaces code:

```
<a4j:status onstop="Richfaces.showModalPanel('mdpMessage')" />
<rich:modalPanel id="mdpMessage" resizeable="false" zindex="5000"
        minHeight="30" minWidth="10" height="70" width="150">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Operation Results" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Messages" />
        <!-- you can add your h:messages here -->
        <a4j:commandButton value="Close"
            onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('mdpMessage')" />
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: I did as you said, but my table is not re-rendered. If I'm refreshing the page after submitting the button, I see that rows has been deleted. But just after refreshing.

Comment: I found the problem! it is not <a4j:commandButton reRender="dtMyData">, it is <a4j:commandButton render="dtMyData">

Comment: @udar_molota I did the code thinking in JSF 1.2 and RF 3.3. I'll take note and post code based on your needs. It would be better if you specify the version you're working with :)